# File sharing on a windows 2003 r2 server

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a Domain with a DC running server 2003 r2 and 2 file servers also running server 2003 r2. The shared folders on one of the file servers cannot be accessed I can ping both ways with ip and name. I have removed the server from the domain and added it back. Even the DC cannot access the file server. I have tried using win explorer and \name\ I can see the server but it says I don,t have permission. I have read forums and have tried various fix with not luck. I have enabled the guest account, added both computer name and user name to the shared folder still no luck, any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked permissions on the folder being shared and the share itself?

Answer (score 1):

Brain storm:

- Check the system event log
- Check the server service is running
- Check the Windows firewall hasn't kicked in on the NICs
- Check the IP settings (though it joined the domain, so probably moot)

  Check "Windows file and print sharing" is bound to the NIC(s)

  Perform a **net view \\<file server>** to check the shares are available remotely

  Like pacey said check the share permissions

  Check the NTFS permissions of the underlying folder being shared

  Try a **net share** on the server to get its perspective of the active shares